# Ошибка при обходе гугл ботом

Tags: seo, поисковые-системы

На сайте есть форма с рейтингом статьи, то есть человек ставит, к примеру, 5 звезд и форма через POST идет в контроллер нужный.

Гугл бот пытается перейти по этой ссылке (само-собой без аргументов) и получает логичную 405 ошибку.

Как правильно объяснить поисковикам, чтобы они туда не лазили, не прописывая в robots.txt

Comment: Ну поставьте простую проверку, если нет аргументов, сделать  301 или 303 редирект, через неделю больше никто не будет проходить по этой ссылке ))

Answer (score 0):

Я не был бы так уверен, что это имеено google-бот, может какой-то сканер им прикрывается. Нужно по-возможности пробить IP.

Можете немного переработать форму, убрать у нее action, добавить url в data-атрибут и сделать запрос через AJAX

Comment: Это гугл бот, информация из гугл вебмастер консоли, он же и жаловался. форма итак через ajax

Comment: А action у формы пустой? Спрячьте от гугла url.

Comment: этот вариант не подойдет. тк я планирую потом еще форму добавить общедоступную на сайте не через ajax, и если я тут решу вопрос так, то придется по новой спрашивать потом. В интернете не нашел нигде как решают эту проблему =(

Comment: Я на сайтах все формы делаю через один скрипт, для которого стандартизированный json - ответ. Он умеет выводить ошибки, выводить алерты, делать простую переадресацию, переадресацию методом POST. 
Очень удобно, я считаю.  Достаточно на все формы добавить определенный класс и подключить js-файл

Answer (score 0):

Можно запретить обращение к определенным путям через [robots.txt](http://www.robotstxt.org/)

Можно фильтровать user-agent в скрипте голосования (и как уже правильно написали - проверять входные данные)